# Sending Email through IIS for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, iis

In asp.net mvc, how can I send email without external SMTP server? Does IIS can help me with this job?

Normally, I can use `SmtpClient` to send email, but I have to config an external server such as *'smtp.gmail.com'* to help me send the mail, also I have to set the credentials for it which we may need to create a new account for our app in Gmail, that's what we want to avoid. What we want to achieve is just send an email to user, and with that email user can confirm their information.

So, any simple method to do this?

Comment: you cant sent an email without an smtp Server. because the smtp Server is the object in the chain that SENDS the email :) and the IIS doesnt implement smtp Server functionality

Comment: @S.L. okay, I see. Is there any public SMTP server allow anonymous access without provide the credentials?

Comment: sure there are. but i wouldnt recommend to use one because 99% of them are marked as spam Servers because of exactly the Point that you can send emails anonymously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant sent an email without an smtp Server. because the smtp Server is the object in the chain that SENDS the email :) and the IIS doesnt implement smtp Server functionality

> SMTPClient -> SMTPServer Sender -> SMTP Server Reciever -> POP -> Email CLient

There are several relay smtp Server without smtp-auth out there but i recommend you to **avoid the use of them** because else YOU will be marked as spam pretty sure.

Comment: Under my local machine, suppose I would choose to use Gmail. I enabled the SSL, and set the credentials correctly. But the exception thrown said `'can't connect to the remote server ...'`. Should I open the port (`587` in this case) in the Windows Firewall?

Comment: if you have a Firewall for outgoing Connections you should open the required ports for the ssl connection